# Length of strings with Unicode in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, unicode

How to calculate the length of a Unicode string in Excel?

I tried both `LEN` and `LENB`, but both of them give the same result.
For non-English words, the result is correct, 5.

```
=LENB("こんにちは")
```

But for other strings, the result is wrong, 4 instead of 3.

```
=LENB("^^")
```

The only solution I found, was to compare all substrings created with the function `LEFT`, but this looks overkill.

```
=1-SUM(-(LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))<>LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1),,2))))
```

The same issue is with the function MID or MIDB. Instead of =MID("^^",2,2), I have to write

```
=RIGHT(LEFT("^^",3),2)
```

Does anybody know a better way?

--- UPDATE 4/25/2023---
After the response from `@JB-007`, I did some more digging, and I found more anomalies.

1. I reduced my function a little, but the answer is different than all other options. :-(

   ```
   =1-SUM(-(LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))<>A1))
   ```
2. If I append a standard ASCII character to ‍♂️, all functions increase by 2, not 1.
3. If I append a standard ASCII character to ‍♂️, all functions increase by 1. That is correct.

In my opinion, all 3 functions should give the same answers. But they are not. The function LEN is the most consistent: it gives the number of code points in the UNICODE character.

For me, in the absence of a function that returns 1 for a UNICODE character (grapheme), the result of the LEN function is useless.

Here are the final results:
[image]

Comment: I would expect LEN to count Unicode codepoints and LENB to count encoded bytes assuming some encoding, but that is probably asking to much of Excel. In my testing it looks like both count UTF16 code units.  Unicode code points <= U+FFFF count as 1 and Unicode code points > U+FFFF count as two, such as (U+1F680) and (U+1F30D).  The Japanese characters are all below <= U+FFFF and count as 1 each.

Comment: [Microsoft says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/len-lenb-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60080&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) "LENB counts 2 bytes per character only when a DBCS language is set as the default language. Otherwise LENB behaves the same as LEN, counting 1 byte per character." but that isn't exactly true either.

Comment: I suspect that Excel counts surrogates for codepoints above [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) e.g.  `` (U+1F680, *ROCKET (0xd83d,0xde80)*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and tried to come up with a solution with some heavy assistance from GPT.

After some back and forth and trying to wrap my head around it, it ended up being this function:

```
Function TrueLength(inputStr As String) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim extraCount As Integer
extraCount = 0
Dim prevCharWasHighSurrogate As Boolean
prevCharWasHighSurrogate = False

For i = 1 To Len(inputStr)
    Dim currentChar As String
    currentChar = Mid(inputStr, i, 1)
    Dim currentCharCode As Long
    currentCharCode = AscW(currentChar)

    If currentCharCode >= &HD800 And currentCharCode <= &HDBFF Then
        extraCount = extraCount + 1
    ElseIf currentCharCode = &H200D Then
        extraCount = extraCount + 1
    ElseIf currentCharCode = &HFE0F Then
        extraCount = extraCount + 2
    End If
Next i

TrueLength = Len(inputStr) - extraCount
End Function
```

The way I understand it it works like this:

- Unicode values between `U+D800` and `U+DBFF` are a surrogate byte found in UTF-16 chars such as emojis and are not counted by the function (or rather added to a list of bytes to be subtracted from the total at the end)
- The value `U+200D` is used to combine emojis so it should also not be counted. Called the [zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner).
- The value `U+FE0F` is even more special as it indicates that a previous sign (which is the ♂ in the case of "‍♂️") was used as a variation of an emoji. So whatever that previous symbol was and this value itself should not be counted. This wikipedia article is relevant as far as I understand: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_Supplement

The breakdown for ‍♂️ is as follows:

1. U+D937 – First part of the surrogate pair that is the shrug emoji; caught by the function and not counted
2. U+DC4D – Second part of the surrogate pair for the shrug emoji – counted by the function as 1 char.
3. U+200D – Zero width joiner and therefore not counted
4. U+2642 – male symbol usually displayed as "♂" – usually counted, however, see Nr. 5
5. U+FE0F – the variation selector supplement that indicates the last symbol being a variation indicator and not its own symbol. In my solution this subtracts 2 from the final count.

I feel like the zero width joiner could maybe be used to not count any character until the next whitespace character maybe? Just an intuition though.

Short conclusion: For a proper grapheme length counter, pretty much every edge case would need to be caught by functions that can correctly interpret unicode values. This seems to be only realistic on a case by case basis as there are many potential issues depending on what sorts of symbols come up. This could warrant a big project in itself.

Answer (score 1):

The non-breaking character(s) associated with   and  are not the same (unicode: 56960 & 57101 resp.); so a simple substitute function cannot be used.  Generally, native text functions in Excel do not handle such chars very well (i.e. emojis, icons etc.).

Your primary two options are thus:

- overkill method that deals with each character in some way
- UDF in VBA

To this end, here's a slightly more parsimonious approach, but arguably just as 'overkill' as you put it:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(UNICODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))))
```

---

*Extra interesting points/notes:*

However, both this and your function will still fail with certain 'special-case' emojis, such as those that have accompanying attributes such as 'gender' or 'complexion/skin tone'.

Take the following for instance (press Win and '>' in Excel to replicate):

‍♀️

which Excel's context description describes as "woman shrugging'.  As might be expected, there is also a 'man shrugging' counterpart:

‍♂️

Disappointingly, whilst Excel offers this variation, both emojis appear in B&W and look very similar to one another:

[image: woman shrugging]

[image: man shrugging]

When there is another emoji present (e.g. ✌️), something v. interesting happens when one clicks on either cell and presses F2 to edit:

woman shrugging shows:
[image: gender-attribute, female]

man shrugging shows:
[image: gender-attribute, male]

*(after escaping the extra female/male attribute icons magically disappear! This doesn't happen without the additional emoji though - presumably a bug of some type, that I'll have to raise with Bill the next time we're playing golf ☺).*

Implications for the above function (col B, 'mid fn') and your function (col C, 'left fn'):

[image: mid fn - col B]

[image: left fn - col C]

Whilst 'your' function in col C gets closer to the correct answer, both are clearly incorrect (wrong is wrong!

---